# how to change the value of a random value within a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am receiving in a function an array with defined values and others to be defined.

```
["y", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

What I am trying to do is that every time I receive this array I check the values that are at null and to one of them, chosen in a random way, I want to set the value "Z" and return the array modified.

For this I am doing the following in my function:

```
    nextValue(array) {
        
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);        
    }
};
```

At this point , which I have found in other references , if I print the value "random = Nan"
and "array[random] = undefined".

How could I modify the value ?

Would there be a better method without the need to extract the value, and modify it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not clear what exactly you want. Assuming the task is "take an array with elements both `null` and some other values, flip one random `null` to some preset string, do that in place", here's what you might use:

```js
function flipRandomNull(arrayWithNulls, character) {
  const indexesOfNulls = arrayWithNulls.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    return item === null ? [...acc, index] : acc;
  }, []);

  if (!indexesOfNulls.length) return; // no nulls for ya, nothing to flip

  const indexToFlip = indexesOfNulls[ Math.random() * indexesOfNulls.length | 0];
  arrayWithNulls[ indexToFlip ] = character;
}

const initialField = ["y", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

[...Array(initialField.length - 1)].forEach(() => {
  flipRandomNull(initialField, 'Z');
  console.log(initialField.join(' | '));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use array.map and array.filter methods to find out the index of null items in your array, then fill a random location of your main array with "z":

```
const arr = ["y", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

const nextValue = (orgArr) => {
    const nullLocations = orgArr
        .map((item, idx) => (item === null ? idx : null))
        .filter((item) => item !== null);
    orgArr[nullLocations[Math.floor(Math.random() * nullLocations.length)]] = "z";
    return orgArr;
};

console.log(nextValue(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this...

```js
let arr = ["y", null, null, null, null, "y", null, null, null];
let size = arr.length;
// size of array

function random() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * size + 1)
  //generate radnom number betwen 0 and size of array
  if (arr[random] === null) {
    arr[random] = "z";
    // if random array  is null set z
    return size = 0;
    //stop loop
  } else {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * size + 1);
    // if not set new radnom number
  }
}

var i = 0;
while (i < size) {
  random()
  i++;
}
// loop function untill it sets radnom array null to z
console.log(arr)
```

Plus even shorter function:

```
function random() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * size + 1)
  arr[random] === null ? (arr[random] = "z", size = 0 ) : (random = Math.floor(Math.random() * size + 1));  
}
```

```js
let arr = ["y", null, "y", "y", null, "y", null, null, null];
let size = arr.length;


var i = 0;
while (i < size) {
  random()
  i++;
}

function random() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * size + 1)
  arr[random] === null ? (arr[random] = "z", size = 0, console.log("set, " + (i + 1) + " trys")) : (random = Math.floor(Math.random() * size + 1));
}


console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%
}
```